# When renaming a file in SharePoint via client object model, the filename gets trimmed if there's a dot in between

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I wrote a small application using the SharePoint client object model, which renames all files inside a SharePoint 2010 document library.
Everything works well, except if the filename should contain a dot somewhere in between, it get's trimmed, starting with the dot.

For example, when the new filename should be "**my fi.le name**" it ends up with "**my fi**" in SharePoint. The extension of the file (.pdf in my case) stays correct by the way.

Here's what I'm doing (in general):

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp.example.com/thesite);
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("mydoclibrary");
ListItemCollection col = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.Load(col);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var doc in col)
{
    if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
        doc["FileLeafRef"] = "my fi.le name";
        doc.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

When I'm renamig the file in SharePoint manually via browser (edit properties), everything works as it should: The dot stays and the filename won't be trimmed at all.

Is `"FileLeafRef"` the wrong property? Any ideas what's the cause here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `FileLeafRef` property it is possible to update file name but without extension.

### How to rename file using SharePoint CSOM

Use [File.MoveTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.moveto.ASPx) to rename a file:

```
public static void RenameFile(ClientContext ctx,string fileUrl,string newName)
{
        var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
        ctx.Load(file.ListItemAllFields);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        file.MoveTo(file.ListItemAllFields["FileDirRef"] + "/" + newName, MoveOperations.Overwrite); 
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    RenameFile(ctx, "/Shared Documents/User Guide.docx", "User Guide 2013.docx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked :-)
It's possible to add the extension, by using **file.ListItemAllFields["File_x0020_Type"]** like:
`file.MoveTo(file.ListItemAllFields["FileDirRef"] + "/" + newName + file.ListItemAllFields["File_x0020_Type"], MoveOperations.Overwrite);`

Comment: Does this method preserve the version history?